# Laptop fan turns on and off in 2-5 second intervals when screen is off

Tags: laptop, display, fan

I have an Acer A315-21-958V and whenever the screen is off (NOT when laptop is asleep, just when the screen is off/black) the fan constantly turns on and off. Powers on for few seconds then off for few and repeats. There could be nothing running or everything running and it will happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings for wake on ....  anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dust or Pet hair build up in the fan. Try vacuuming and/or blowing out cooling vents. Should see better results. If really clogged up you can take apart the fan housing and clean the dust build up.
2. Thermal paste on CPU is not longer workings, reapply new thermal paste.
3. Cooling fan is not spinning fast enough to keep it cool (not likely)
4. Bad design, system runs hot. Could add a laptop cooling pad to it.

Let us know if any other these worked.

Sometimes when idle the operating system starts a task like virus scanning, running updates, defrag disk, or similar system maintenance. Those task can be CPU intense enough to spike CPU temps. Open Task manager and let it run for at least a minute and see what your CPU usage is registering. If your running linux then use htop. Also trying turning off wifi/bluetooth and see if the behavior changes. Worst case scenario you could have malware.